# Ogre dynamic link libraries

Tags: linux, ogre, dynamic-library

I am trying to dynamically link the ogre libraries. I was able to get past linking libraries for the samples except the sample browser.

Here is the log..

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/Sample_SSAO.so
[100%] Built target Sample_SSAO
Scanning dependencies of target SampleBrowserDummy
[100%] Building CXX object Samples/Browser/CMakeFiles/SampleBrowserDummy.dir/dummy.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared module ../../lib/libSampleBrowserDummy.so
Updated and renamed default.properties to project.properties
Updated local.properties
No project name specified, using Activity name 'NativeActivity'.
If you wish to change it, edit the first line of build.xml.
Added file /home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/build_dynamic/SampleBrowserNDK/build.xml
Added file /home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/build_dynamic/SampleBrowserNDK/proguard-project.txt
make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1. Add `+' to parent make rule.
Compile++ thumb : OgreSampleBrowser <= FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp:28:33: error: FileSystemLayerImpl.h: No such file or directory
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp:32: error: 'FileSystemLayerImpl' has not been declared
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp:36: error: 'FileSystemLayerImpl' has not been declared
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp:36: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Ogre' with no type
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp:36: error: expected ',' or '...' before '::' token
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp:40: error: 'FileSystemLayerImpl' has not been declared
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp:40: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Ogre' with no type
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp:40: error: expected ',' or '...' before '::' token
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp:40: error: non-member function 'bool OgreBites::fileExists(int)' cannot have cv-qualifier
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp: In function 'bool OgreBites::fileExists(int)':
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp:42: error: 'path' was not declared in this scope
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp:42: error: 'access' was not declared in this scope
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp: At global scope:
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp:45: error: 'FileSystemLayerImpl' has not been declared
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp:45: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Ogre' with no type
/home/mihir/workspace/ogre_3d/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.cpp:45: error: expected ',' or '...' before '::' token
make[3]: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/OgreSampleBrowser/FileSystemLayerImpl_Android.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [lib/libSampleBrowserDummy.so] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Samples/Browser/CMakeFiles/SampleBrowserDummy.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The header files that it is complaining about being missing are present in my working directory. I also tried to manually copy the header files that it complained about and this is what i get.

```
/home/mihir/workspace/lab126/ogre_3d/build_dynamic/Samples/include/SampleBrowser‌_Android.h:332: error: expected '>' before 'AndroidEGLWindow'
/home/mihir/workspace/lab126/ogre_3d/build_dynamic/Samples/include/SampleBrowser‌_Android.h:332: error: expected '(' before 'AndroidEGLWindow' 
/home/mihir/workspace/lab126/ogre_3d/build_dynamic/Samples/include/SampleBrowser‌​_Android.h:332: error: 'AndroidEGLWindow' was not declared in this scope 
/home/mihir/workspace/lab126/ogre_3d/build_dynamic/Samples/include/SampleBrowser‌​_Android.h:332: error: expected primary-express
```

Comment: It seems you are missing the header files (`*.h`). What system is this? What did you install previously?

Comment: ok so I am trying to get this in a Linux environment for Android OS. I was able to build the Ogre libraries statically based on the instructions given on the wiki page on Ogre. However, I want to be able to build it dynamically.

The header files that it is complaining about being missing are present in my working directory.

I also tried to manually copy the header files that it complained about and this is what i get.

Comment: /home/mihir/workspace/lab126/ogre_3d/build_dynamic/Samples/include/SampleBrowser_Android.h:332: error: expected '>' before 'AndroidEGLWindow'
/home/mihir/workspace/lab126/ogre_3d/build_dynamic/Samples/include/SampleBrowser_Android.h:332: error: expected '(' before 'AndroidEGLWindow'
/home/mihir/workspace/lab126/ogre_3d/build_dynamic/Samples/include/SampleBrowser_Android.h:332: error: 'AndroidEGLWindow' was not declared in this scope
/home/mihir/workspace/lab126/ogre_3d/build_dynamic/Samples/include/SampleBrowser_Android.h:332: error: expected primary-express

Comment: It seems this error is occurring while linking the samples. If you do not need those, you could disable their building in cmake. It's not a proper solution, but it might be the simplest course of action.